# Error in panda from_csv datetime parsing

Tags: datetime, pandas, lambda

I have a csv file, where the first 3 columns of each row represent a date, like:

2013,1,1,... (first row)

I want to automatically convert the first three columns of each row in the csv into a python datetime object using the following code:

```
parseDate = lambda y,m,d: datetime.datetime(y,m,d)
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(csvPath, index_col=False,header=None, parse_dates... 
   =[0,1,2],date_parser= parseDate)
```

But get an error in the date_parser part.

However, just doing

```
dtime = parseDate(2003,1,1)
```

works as expected, so my lambda expression actually seems to be correct.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't think you need your lambda please try `df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(csvPath, index_col=False,header=None, parse_dates=[[0,1,2]])`

Comment: Thanks, that works. But what if I really needed a datetime.datetime(2001,1,2) object? Why cant I use the lambda expression?

Comment: Heres the error :

TypeError: from_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date_parser'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 3.365s
FAILED (errors=1)
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method DebuggerLoop.loop of <ptvsd.visualstudio_py_debugger.DebuggerLoop object at 0x00000000027696A0>>

Comment: To use a date parser you normally pass a dict with column name as the key and your parser as the value like so `date_parser={'col':parseDate}`, in your situation I'm not sure you can pass multiple columns in this fashion

Comment: The alternative could be to do this as a post-processing step if it's not possible using your date parser. For this example though it is not necessary as the inbuilt parser can handle your data inputs

Comment: Also edit your error trace into the question so it is clearer for other readers